# MAPISendMail don't insert the originator

Tags: c++, c, windows

I use the simple MAPI function MAPISendMail in the way that's described in the MSDN sample, so I set the Originator to NULL.
The dialogue comes up, I can define recipients (even programmatically with the RecipDesc structure) and gives me an SUCCESS_SUCCESS.

But if I look in my outbox, then there is no originator, and Exchange says 'cannot send mail' (or so).

Environment:

Win XP SP3
Outlook 2003

Domain system with Outlook Exchange

Any hints ?

TIA

Klaus-Werner Konrad

Comment: *Very* difficult for MSFT to every retire an API.  The only way is to not have anybody left that knows how to make it work.  Same here.

Comment: Sorry - I;'m not an native english (american) speaker :-(

Answer (score 0):

My implementation does work (I am using Windows 7 64 bit with Microsoft Exchange).  I have the following:

```
    MapiRecipDesc sender;

    ::ZeroMemory(&sender, sizeof(MapiRecipDesc));
    sender.ulRecipClass = MAPI_TO;
    sender.lpszName = "myemail@msn.com";
    Message.lpOriginator = &sender;
```

Make sure that the text is still present when the MAPISendMail is called, as the structure merely points to this text.